# How to persist a file in /usr/local in embedded FreeNAS

Tags: openvpn, freenas

I have embedded FreeNAS, version 8.2 beta. Now I would like to install openvpn, of course persisting between updates.

I have managed to get the program itself persist by using

```
mount -wu /
pkg_add -r openvpn
mount -ro /
```

Also I got the the `openvpn_enable="YES"` line to persist by editing `/conf/base/etc/rc.conf`

My problem is to persist the `/usr/local/etc/openvpn` folder with therein my `openvpn.conf` configuration and key files. How can I persist those?

Comment: [This page mentions `openvpn` a lot](http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Plugins#Installing_FreeBSD_Packages_with_pkg_add), there seems to be `openvpn_configfile` directive that you probably use in `/conf/base/etc/rc.conf`... But I'm completely unsure if this gets you any further as I don't know FreeNAS' update process.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the new Plugin system. Although there isn't an OpenVPN plugin right now, you can install software within the jail. The jail is not affected on FreeNAS updates.
And if you so, you might want to create a plugin and contribute it to the FreeNAS community :-)

Further readings: http://doc.freenas.org/index.php/Plugins

Answer (score 1):

I just went through getting this working of FreeNAS 8.2 myself.  I've got a bunch of notes about the process on my blog at http://joepaetzel.wordpress.com/2012/07/24/openvpn-on-freenas-8-2/

Short version is you need to copy your config files for openvpn to /conf/base/etc/local/etc/openvpn
and
/conf/base/etc/rc.conf

To do that, you need to make the filesystem writeable.
`# mount -uw /`

You really do not want to try to make this work in the plugin jail.